# C programming for changing all capital letters and changing all lower letters

Tags: c

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char chaCap(char n);

int main()
{
  char ch,a;
  printf("Enter Sentence\n");

  while((ch=getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    chaCap(ch);
    printf("%c",a);
  }
  printf(" \n");

  return 0;
}
void chaCap(char n)
{
  if(n >= 'a' && n <='z')
      n-=32;

}
```

I need

1. Ask user to enter sentence
2. Convert the sentence to all capital letters and print
3. Convert the sentence to all lower case letters and print
4. Convert the each character if it is upper to lower and vice versa.

I made for changing capital letters, but i couldn't make lower and vice versa.

when I made code for 2. and 3, getchar() became nothing...

Comment: `ch = toupper(ch); printf("%c", ch);`

Comment: Hint: Something similar how you made small to capital by subtracting 32, you should also add some thing when the letter is capital to make it smaller.

Comment: I would suggest get the ascii value of character then add the logic:-  If ascii value is between 65-97 then +32 else if 97-122 then -32. Thats it. Try doing this...

Comment: Your program doesn't it gave you any error.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **tolower()** function :

```
  while((ch=getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    printf("%c", tolower(ch));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to return value in function `chaCap(char n)`,

```
char chaCap(char n)//need to return char instead of void
{
  if(n >= 'a' && n <='z')
      n-=32;
  return n; // return capital letter here
}
```

and then get return value when call it in `main()`,

```
int main()
{
  //... 
  while((ch=getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    a = chaCap(ch); // get return value
    printf("%c",a);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *strlwr(char *str){
    char *s;
    for(s = str; *s; ++s){
        if(isupper(*s))
            *s = tolower(*s);
    }
    return str;
}

char *strupr(char *str){
    char *s;
    for(s = str; *s; ++s){
        if(islower(*s))
            *s = toupper(*s);
    }
    return str;
}

char *strvrs(char *str){
    char *s;
    for(s = str; *s; ++s){
        if(islower(*s))
            *s = toupper(*s);
        else if(isupper(*s))
            *s = tolower(*s);
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void){
    int ch;
    size_t i = 0, size = 32;
    char *str = malloc(size);

    printf("Enter Sentence\n");

    while((ch=getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF){
        str[i++] = ch;
        str[i++] = '\0';
        if(i-- == size){
            char *temp = realloc(str, (size += 32));
            if(!temp){
                fprintf(stderr, "realloc error\n");
                free(str);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            str = temp;
        }
    }
    printf("original   : %s\n", str);
    printf("vice versa : %s\n", strvrs(str));
    printf("upper      : %s\n", strupr(str));
    printf("lower      : %s\n", strlwr(str));
    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `ch` as a global variable.

The following program will change all uppercase letters to lower case and all lower case letters to upper case.

Your program needed few modifications to get the desired result.I have made the required changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void chaCap(char ch);
char ch;

int main()
{

  printf("Enter Sentence\n");

  while((ch=getchar()) != '\n')
  {
   chaCap(ch);
    printf("%c",ch);
  }
  printf(" \n");

  return 0;
}
void chaCap(char ch)
{
  if(ch >= 'a' && ch <='z')
     ::ch=ch-32;
  else if(ch>='A'&&ch<='Z')
     ::ch=ch+32;
}
```