# Segmentation fault in C when trying to run

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I am new to the C language, I am attempting to write a program that outputs text in either upper or lower case, by inputting either -u or -l. The program compiles, however when I run it, it gives me a segmentation fault. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;
  if(strcmp(argv[1],"-u")){
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++){
        printf("%s ",toupper(argv[i]));
      }

  }
  else if(strcmp(argv[1],"-l")){
    for(j=0;j<argc;j++){
        printf("%s ",tolower(argv[j]));
    }
  }
  else{
    for(k=0;k<argc;k++){
        printf("%s ",argv[k]);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `strupr` instead of `toupper` and  `strlwr` instead of `tolower`,

Comment: Also consider the case argc < 2

Comment: `strupr()`/`strlwr()` aren't C nor POSIX and might only be available as an extension to the latter, so aren't portabe. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: [for 7bit code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31290393/971127)

Answer (score 2):

`toupper` & `tolower` take an int representing a character and returning an int representing that character as upper or lower case (respectively).

You're doing 2 things wrong with that:

1. You're passing in the address of a char array (not a single character)
2. You're using the returned value (int) as if it was a char array (passing it as an input to `printf` with "%s")

So you're getting some garbage out of the function, and then sending `printf` into unmapped memory address -> that's your seg-fault.

Comment: so how should I use toupper & tolower?

Comment: Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) (and generally, learn how to use documentation, become friends with google, and good luck learning C!)

Answer (score 0):

To make life easy, also consider using the getopt command.

Here you will find an example: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt

Comment: This does address the segmentation fault problem. Therefore you should have posted this as a comment on the question. I see that you don't have the reputation to do that, so please try to earn the needed reputation first.